# Dagger 2 inject from two component

Tags: android, dagger-2

I run into  a problm that I can't figure it out. I'm using Dagger2 as a DI framework in my Android app. I was trying to inject my activity with two different components but [apparently it can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352796/dependencies-from-two-components-in-one-activity). The obvious solution seems to create a unique component with all the behaviour needed, but I've different scopes in my modules. So what would be the right approach? should I have the same scopes even though that wasn't the plan?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to inject  two component into one class or activity, you should change your component structure and divide it into subcomponent or create a separate component for each class (it's not recommended),

this link discussed your problem too :
[Dependencies from two components in one activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352796/dependencies-from-two-components-in-one-activity)